# Tkinter performance when packing many widgets

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a GUI in python using Tkinter and have had some performance issues when packing many widgets onto the screen, for example packing a 50x50 grid of buttons takes a few seconds.

It seems to be the process of drawing (or arranging?) the widgets onto the screen which takes the time. I have tried using both the grid and place geometry managers.

I am wondering if using multiprocessing might speed this up? I would welcome any other suggestions for any way in which this could be significantly sped up.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
for i in range(50):
    for j in range(50):
        widget = tk.Frame(frame, bd=2, relief='raised', height=10, width=10)
        widget.grid(row=i, column=j) # using place is barely quicker
tk.Button(root, text='pack', command=frame.pack).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tkinter isn't thread safe so multiprocessing will almost certainly not help, personally I found that in some cases that placing the widgets on a canvas [`canvas.create_window`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_window.html) was quicker to redraw but harder to resize / manipulate.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I just tried this with the example above and the difference is minimal if any.

Comment: I mean... you're instantiating 2500 objects that all need instantiated, unique keys generated, communicated into the Tcl interpreter and instantiated there, bound back-and-forth, and then arranged. As far as GUIs go, 2500 objects is usually a little much to go through a wrapper from one interpreted language to another. What is your goal? If you just want a gridlike construct, don't use 2500 frames, use a canvas and `draw` some squares (fewer/simpler objects)

Comment: @Delioth It's for a minesweeper game - I was making use of the properties available with Tkinter widgets for displaying the buttons. I may have to draw images on a canvas or something similar instead, however.

Comment: (From memory, so may be flawed) I believe that canvasses do have clicky support (and can know what's underneath?)

Comment: Given a click on a cell, the game logic needs the cell coordinates, not the cell string id.  Given k pixel by k pixel cells, the cell coordinates of a click at x, y would be x//k, y//k. I would just use this in a click event handler bound to '<Button-1>' on the canvas.

Comment: @terry I'm well aware of that, but I use the options of displaying the frames of each button as different thicknesses etc depending on if they're clicked.

Comment: One approach based on what @TerryJanReddy brought in, you could use a canvas, draw lines instead of the buttons and "On-Click" put a rectangle onto the coordinates enclosed by the lines. That would heavily decrease the amount of widgets and speed it up.

Comment: Maybe this would be better suited at [CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) or [Programmers](https://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @R4PH43L when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Thank you for pointing that out, will keep it in mind for the next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the best solution did end up being to use a canvas and draw onto it, rather than to pack so many widgets, which seems to have absolute limitations on its speed.

I used the built-in buttons by effectively taking a screenshot to create images of the unclicked and clicked states. Suppose the image files are stored as `im_up.png` and `im_down.png`, then the code below illustrates the canvas solution.

```
import Tkinter as tk
# Uses Python Imaging Library.
from PIL import Image as ImagePIL, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width=500, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
images = dict()
for name in ['up', 'down']:
    im = ImagePIL.open('im_{}.png'.format(name))
    # Resize the image to 10 pixels square.
    im = im.resize((10, 10), ImagePIL.ANTIALIAS)
    images[name] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im, name=name)
def set_cell_image(coord, image):
    # Get position of centre of cell.
    x, y = ((p + 0.5) * 10 for p in coord)
    canvas.create_image(x, y, image=image)
for i in range(50):
    for j in range(50):
        set_cell_image((i, j), images['up'])
def click(event):
    coord = tuple(getattr(event, p)/10 for p in ['x', 'y'])
    set_cell_image(coord, images['down'])
canvas.bind('<Button-1>', click)
root.mainloop()
```