# How to optimize tkinter button creation to do it faster?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to create a 20x20 grid where I can detect which box has been clicked. I ended up creating 400 buttons to know directly which box had been clicked, but the creation takes a long time (especially after multiple uses for some reason). I would like to know if there is a way to do it faster?

I started with this code:

```
from tkinter import * 
import random as rd

root = Tk()
for r in range(20):
    for c in range(20):
        case = Button(root, bg="gray", activebackground="red", relief=SUNKEN)
        case.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky=NSEW)
root.mainloop()
```

And now I use this one because it looks more beautiful to me:

```
from tkinter import * 
import random as rd

root = Tk()
positions = [(r, c) for r in range(20) for c in range(20)]
rd.shuffle(positions)
for position in positions:
    case = Button(root, bg="gray", activebackground="red", relief=SUNKEN)
    case.grid(row=position[0], column=position[1], sticky=NSEW)
root.mainloop()
```

Maybe creating the button before the loop and putting a copy of it in the grid 400 times might speed the process, I have tried, but haven't managed to get it to work.

Hope you could help me :)

Comment: I don't think there is a faster way unless you find a better library other than tkinter.

Comment: This is unfortunate, I can't use something else because it's forced, so I'm going to leave the question open for a while in case someone has a solution and keep it for now. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You can try creating rectangles on a `tkinter.Canvas` and check where the user clicked but I have no idea if it will be faster or slower. What exactly are you tying to do? My guess would be a minesweeper game

Comment: It's not a minesweeper, in fact it's a game called "blokus" and it's just the grid of the game. The rectangle could be a solution, but I like the buttons, because it already have a small and beautiful border, I can just put a command there to change their color and I can easily know which button was clicked.

Comment: You can also use an image of a button inside a `tkinter.Canvas`

Comment: I tried using rectangles, but I'm not sure how to make it in order to fill its grid box, I tried with a label, but it takes the same time, so it will not be worth it

Comment: The problem with using canvas with an image it's that it's event more complicated to use after in the code, and it will not be faster :/
I think there's no other solutions than using buttons and wait a bit :(


The only solution to this problem could be that if someone knows how to make these 400 buttons faster for example by creating the button before the loop and putting a copy of it in the grid 400 times, I have tried that, but haven't managed to get it to work.

Comment: You can create the buttons in a loop (you can have a progress bar as well) then `place`/`grid`/`pack` them on the screen after all of them have been created. Having a progress bar makes your program look 10 times better :D. Also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38312592/tkinter-performance-when-packing-many-widgets).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried creating the buttons before placing them all in once, but it seems like nothing had changed, so it might be the placing which is the problem. I think I will create a progress bar as you suggested because it seems to be a good solution :) Also thank you for the link! It is helpful :)

Comment: @hinzelin: _"The problem with using canvas with an image it's that it's event more complicated to use after in the code"_ - why do you say that? Why is it more complicated?

Comment: Your code takes about 1 second on my machine. Are you saying it's considerably slower on yours?

Comment: For me, it's easier with buttons because they automatically fill the space I give them, I can directly give them the command to execute and chose their animation for example. This is not impossible with the canvas but I begin with tkinter, and it seems a lot more difficult to make them have the good size when we resize the main window with other element (to keep the same ratio) and to deal with event to just execute a command after a click.

Comment: For the time, it takes from 1 to 5 seconds, but I think I will try to create a progress bar as the time it takes is not the main problem of the project and I just want something beautiful.